# How can I speed up multiple arithmetic operations on pandas.Series by performing them all at once?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have code like this:

```
large_series += add_factor
large_series *= multiply_factor
```

Where `large_series` is a large `pandas.Series`.

This code is taking up a lot of my runtime, and I'd like to optimize it. One observation is that rather than doing this as two separate operations - first add to the whole `Series`, then multiply the whole `Series` - it can be done with a single operation: increment and multiply each value in the `Series`.

How can that be done?

I've heard of JIT optimizers for Pandas like Numba, and wondering whether such can help as well.

Comment: is the actual code more complicated? or is there any reason why you couldn't just do `large_series = multiply_factor*(large_series + add_factor)` ?

Comment: @ScottStaniewicz your code does the exact same thing and has the exact same cost, it just puts it on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

One way to speed it up is by using more processors. You can do this by using `import modin.pandas as pd` (you have to install first)

## With Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[random.randint(0, 1e3) for _ in range(int(1e6))]})

add_factor = 2193
multiply_factor = 4353

s = time.time()
df.a += add_factor
df.a *= multiply_factor
print(time.time()-s, 'seconds elapsed')
0.13749933242797852 seconds elapsed
```

## With Modin.Pandas

```
import modin.pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[random.randint(0, 1e3) for _ in range(int(1e6))]})

add_factor = 2193
multiply_factor = 4353

s = time.time()
df.a += add_factor
df.a *= multiply_factor
print(time.time()-s, 'seconds elapsed')
0.08657097816467285 seconds elapsed
```